Relation bitween Mandelstam Variables in three-body final state
What is the relation between Mandelstam variables in the three body final state?
There are 5 independent Mandelstam variables. What is the relationship between them?

Linked.

So if I integrate in the phase space, that I can write as $\frac{1}{s 128 {\pi}^3}ds_{13}ds_{12}$, I will be a cross section that depend from 3 Mandelstam variables, if I don't fix $s=(p+p')^2$, whre p' and p are the 4-momentum of the upcoming particles?

@CosmasZachos ?

Sorry, I'm not going to work out your "homework" details, given the source.
